# Etymology/origin of the name "Ishmael"

Tags: words, names, tanach

What is the etymology of the Biblical name "Ishmael"?

Was this name ever used for any of the Biblical characters before [Ishmael](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ishmael), the son of Abraham?

Answer (score 3):

Genesis 16:15 tells you the origin of the name: Abraham named him that. [*Rashi*](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/8211/showrashi/true#v15) explains he did so with divine inspiration, in which case God *likely* (IMO) implied the same meaning as he had in verse 11: "because God שמע, heard, your pain".

No Ishmaels prior to Abraham's son are listed in the Bible. (That doesn't mean none existed. Most people aren't mentioned in the Bible.)

Answer (score 3):

Gen 16:11

And the angel of the LORD said unto her: 'Behold, thou art with child, and shalt bear a son; and thou shalt call his name Ishmael, because the LORD hath heard thy affliction.

So etymologically, the name develops from the Hebrew root "sh-m-a" meaning "hear" and e-l, god's name. Those roots, are then combined (in one of many possible ways) to create a name from word/ideas.

Comment: Names indicate origin and invoke reference but don't have meaning. When baby books list "meaning" they are pointing to base words and source material unless the name is independently already a word.

Comment: And God giving a name makes the naming and the reference meaningful and the name significant but it doesn't change the presence or lack of inherent meaning.